# 2 Facebook like buttons for same URL, with different get variables, seeing the same like count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, urlvariables

I generate a unique variable for each user on my site that is built into their referral link. When I put that link into a facebook like button the like count is separate for each link.

Here is my example:

UserA:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com?refer=3323"></div>
```

User B:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com?refer=2355"></div>
```

Both users effectivly have the same link, but just a different referral code. I want them both to see our example.com 'like count' but instead, each sees '0 likes.'

Is it possible to have them both see the same like count? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Facebook's fb_ref parameter:

```
<fb:like ref="top_left"></fb:like>
```

Or in iframe notation:

```
<iframe src="...&ref=top_left"></iframe>
```

When a reader clicks through Facebook back to your website, Facebook creates this link on the fly:

*http://www.facebook.com/l.php?fb_ref=top_left&fb_source=profile_oneline*

So in your case use this as your Like configuration:

```
<fb:like ref="3323"></fb:like>
```

or this:

```
<fb:like ref="refer-3323"></fb:like>
```

What you get back is: fb_ref="3323" or fb_ref="refer-3323", respectively. It should be feasible for you to convert this into your desired reflink.

This is untested, but well documented:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Make sure the two urls have the same `og:url`, aka. the canonical url.

Answer (score 0):

The URL used in the Like plugin should be common [for all users]. Then only the like count will be displayed as you expect.

In the code above, its different for User A and User B. Instead you just specify the **data-href as 'http://example.com'**.

May I know why you have specified the referral ID in the url?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a wanker way around it but I used the HTML5 code for one and the iFrame for the second.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/